The quadratic equation $a_1x^2-a_2x+a_3=0$ $a_1, a_2, a_3\in \mathbb N$ has two distinct roots $\in(1,2)$, then what is the least value of $a_1$?
If the quadratic equation $f(x)=a_1x^2-a_2x+a_3=0$  where $a_1, a_2, a_3\in \mathbb N^+$ has two distinct roots belonging to the interval $(1,2)$, then what is the least value of $a_1$?
my attempt
$D\gt0, f(1)\gt0, f(2)\gt0$ since natural number $a_1\ge1$ so leading coefficient is +ve i.e. an upward parabola.
$$\implies a_2^2-4a_1a_3\gt0$$
$$a_1-a_2+a_3\gt0$$
$$4a_1-2a_2+a_3\gt0$$
So Now I have three unknown and three inequalities how to handle it? What should I do now?
Edit 1
Since $f(1), f(2)\neq0$ but are natural number. So more precisely I can say the following
$$a_1-a_2+a_3\ge1$$
$$4a_1-2a_2+a_3\ge1$$
Edit 2
Let $\alpha, \beta$ be the roots of this quation then, $$\alpha+\beta=\dfrac {a_2}{a_1} \qquad \alpha \beta = \dfrac{a_3}{a_1}$$
 I get one more inequality
$${\alpha+\beta\over 2}= \dfrac{a_2}{2a_1}\in (1\; ,\; 2)$$
$$\implies2a_1<a_2<4a_1$$
$$\implies 4a_1-a_2>0 \\
a_2-2a_1>0$$
Now as $1\le a_1<\dfrac{a_2^2}{4a_3}\\
a_2^2>4a_1$ THEN I HAVE
$$a_1^2-a_1a_2+\dfrac{a_2^2}{4}>a_1$$
 $$4a_1^2-2a_1a_2+\dfrac{a_2^2}{4}>a_1$$
$$\implies (2a_1-a_2)^2>4a_1 \\
(4a_1-a_2)^2>4a_1$$
still no progress.

Hint: I should start from the roots as you know something about them - you might make more progress that way.

Consider a quadratic with two real roots $>2$. Then all your inequalities are satisfied but the required condition in the question is not met. You also need $1<a_2/2a_1<2$.

With this in mind, a Python search reveals the minimal value of $a_1=5$ achieved with quadratic $5x^2-15x+11$.

Yes @Sahaj $a_1=5$ is the given answer. I missed that inequality before, but still couldn't make any progress.

This is a pretty "well-known" problem, esp when the roots are in $(0,1)$ which leads to the polynomial $5x^2 - 5x+1$. Shifting it to the right by 1 would then yield Sahara's discovery. $\quad$ The best approach that I know of, is to observe that $0 < (\alpha-1)(2-\alpha) \leq 1/4$ and hence $16f(1)f(2) < a^2$ (WHY strict inequality?) thus $ a \geq 5$.

There are several duplicates on the site, esp if you account for the translation, like this and this.  The writeup are still a bit more painful than the approach that I suggested.

@CalvinLin you told good. This method is very hard to think.  that means you are talking that "this is the only method to solve" this question?

@user1318878 It's not that hard to come up with.  We have $f(1) \geq 1$ and $f(1) = a (1-\alpha)(1-\beta)$, which are the building blocks of the proof, so it makes sense that we want to bound $(\alpha-1)(2-\alpha)$ which "obviously" is $ \leq 1/4$.  $\quad$ There are other methods, like if you see the posts that I linked to. Trial and error happens to work for the case when roots are in $(0,1)$, because we can take $ c = 1$ then. But for roots in $(1, 2)$, then $ c = 1$ doesn't yield the minimum $a$.

You're on the right track with the observations that $f(1) \geq 1, f(2) \geq 1$. How we can exploit this information?
Steps towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

Recall that $f(1) = a(1-\alpha) ( 1-\beta)$, and $ f(2) = a(2-\alpha)(2 - \beta)$.
So, we have $ a^2(1-\alpha) ( 1-\beta)(2-\alpha)(2 - \beta) = f(1)f(2) \geq 1$.
Show that $(\alpha - 1)(2- \alpha) \leq \frac{1}{4}$, with equality iff $ \alpha = \frac{3}{2}$.
Hence, $(1-\alpha) ( 1-\beta)(2-\alpha)(2 - \beta) < \frac{1}{16}$.

Why do we have strict inequality?


Thus $ \frac{ a^2}{16} > a^2 (1-\alpha) ( 1-\beta)(2-\alpha)(2 - \beta) \geq 1 $

So $ a \geq 5$.


We're not yet done as we still need to show that $ a = 5$ can be achieved.

Consider $f(x) = 5x^2 + bx + c$.
Observe that since $ 2 > \frac{ 5^2}{16} > f(1)f(2)$. Thus we require $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1$.
Solving this system gives us $ 5 + b + c = 1, 20 + 2b + c = 1 \Rightarrow b = -15, c = 11$.
A quick check of $ - \frac{b}{2a} \in (1,2) $ demonstrates that this quadratic has distinct roots between $(1, 2)$, hence we are done.



Notes

If we couldn't show strict inequality in step 4, then we'd only have $ a \geq 4$ in step 5. To continue from here, we could subsequently eliminate $ a= 4$ (EG by showing that no such quadratic exists per step 6).
In particular, $5x^2 - 15x + 11$ is the unique quadratic that satisfies the conditions with minimal $a$.


@Sahaj Thanks. Fixed.
